# Eleventy Nunjucks extend template block renders empty space

Tags: html, nunjucks, eleventy

Hello :) I've set up a basic @11ty project. My templates are `.html` and my template engines are `njk`.

While `{% include %}` for partials and `{% extend %}` for layouts works as expected, I cannot get `{% block %}` to work.

Here's a stripped-down repo: https://github.com/wcDogg/eleventy-test-njk-blocks.git.

This is in `_includes/layouts/base.html`:

```html
<main>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  {% block test %}{% endblock %}
  {{ content | safe }}
</main>
```

This is in `_includes/layous/page-blog.html`:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block test %}
<a href="#">Test Link</a>
{% endblock %}
```

When I use the `layout: "layouts/page-blog.html"`, it extends as expected, but the `block` renders as empty space - as seen on `./public/blog/index.html`.

This is foundational to how I'd like to use @11ty - any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code error on my end. Fixed in repo if interested in the example :)